# Why Status Bar simulated metric is missing in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard, xcode-storyboard

As stated in the title, and as visible from the linked image, I'm missing the status bar simulated metric drop down menu since Xcode 9.

This is true no matter the project, so I'm assuming it is not configuration dependent.

Is there a specific reason why this feature has been removed?

[image: Status Bar option removed]

In a view with a dark background, being unable to change the status bar simulated metrics causes the dark status bar text to be unreadable:

[image]

Comment: I thought this is what layout guides and insets are for now..  Basically they want you to constrain your view to these guides and depending on if it's in a nav or tab bar, it will automatically inset itself into the space available..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51451284/set-status-bar-style-in-xcode-10

Answer (score -1):

The status bar does not show in the view controller now on the storyboard so there is no need to include this as it won't affect your layout.

If you want to remove the status bar or change its style, you can do so using code or by change the project settings.

Comment: meaning that if I disable it for a view controller it will leave a 20px white space on top? I don't understand this, how can it not affect the layout? Is there an official reference for this change?

Comment: If its disabled it the view will go to the top of the screen so there will be no gap. Im not sure why it was removed, but maybe to do with the new Safe Areas in Xcode 9.

Comment: You're right the space occupied by status bar is automatically assigned during run time