# Set status bar style in Xcode 10

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using Xcode Version 10.0 beta 4. I keep getting this warning `Setter for 'statusBarStyle' was deprecated in iOS 9.0: Use -[UIViewController preferredStatusBarStyle]`.
I change the status bar style in my scrollViewDidScroll function with `UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .default` after the user has scrolled down far enough. Is there any way I can continue to do this without receiving this warning?

Comment: duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38862208/preferredstatusbarstyle-removed-in-swift-3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have been doing was *always* wrong; it's just that the expected deprecation has finally come.

Do what the error message says. Implement `preferredStatusBarStyle` in the top-level view controller (or some view controller that it consults). When the value changes, call `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate` so that `preferredStatusBarStyle` will be consulted again.

Comment: Couldn't implement this before for whatever reason so I settled with the other way of doing it. I guess I was stumped setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate. Appreciate the support.

Answer (score 0):

Actually `statusBarStyle` was deprecated, use below code in `AppDelegate` to remove the warning.

```
var darkMode = false
var preferredStatusBarStyle : UIStatusBarStyle {
    return darkMode ? .default : .lightContent
}
```